# QGraphicsItem custom class-> type() not working

Tags: c++, qt, class, qgraphicsitem

I have two custom types placed on a QGraphicsScene, this is their declaration:

```
class FotoGebouw : public QGraphicsItem
{
public:
    explicit FotoGebouw();
    ~FotoGebouw();
    Gebouw *linkGebouw;
    enum ItemType { TypeFotoGebouw = UserType + 1, TypeFotoPlantage = UserType + 2};
    int type(){ return TypeFotoGebouw; }
signals:  
public slots: 
};
```

and

```
class FotoPlantage : public QGraphicsItem
{
public:
    explicit FotoPlantage();
    ~FotoPlantage();
    Plantage *linkPlantage;
    enum ItemType { TypeFotoGebouw = UserType + 1, TypeFotoPlantage = UserType + 2};
    int type(){ return TypeFotoPlantage; }   
signals:  
public slots: 
};
```

Now, when I select an item on the QGraphicsScene, I want to find out which type of those two classes it is, but how do I do this? I tried the following, but it always returns the same type... :S thanks in advance

```
    QGraphicsItem *item = bordscene->selectedItems().at(0);
        if (item->type()==7)
            checkGebouwSelectie();
        else if (item->type()==8)
            checkPlantageSelectie();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't actually overriding the type function. Your `int type()` function is non-const, while [the class documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qgraphicsitem.html#type) shows that the virtual QGraphicsItem function is const. The constness needs to match for your function to override of the QGraphicsItem function.

If you have a C++11 compiler, you can specify [override](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/override) to ensure it is a compiler error if your function does not actually override a virtual method. As of Qt5, there is a macro `Q_DECL_OVERRIDE` defined in [QtGlobal](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qtglobal.html#Q_DECL_OVERRIDE) which will become the override keyword for compilers that support it, or nothing for compilers that do not.

I also notice you're also checking `item->type()==7` and `item->type()==8`. In the version of Qt I have handy (4.7.2), those type values correspond to QGraphicsPixmapItem and QGraphicsTextItem, respectively. Are you sure those are the values you're looking for? I'd expect the comparisons to be `item->type() == FotoGebouw::TypeFotoGebouw` and `item->type() == FotoGebouw::TypeFotoPlantage`.

Comment: none of the methods seem to work :S tried making it const, tried using override and tried a different compiler :S

Comment: @CédricVandelaer Great! I've added my comment to the answer. Since that solved your problem, could you accept it?

Answer (score 0):

There will be problem when you use `qgraphicsitem_cast` with your method,

```
template <class T> inline T qgraphicsitem_cast(QGraphicsItem *item)
{
    return int(static_cast<T>(0)->Type) == int(QGraphicsItem::Type)
        || (item && int(static_cast<T>(0)->Type) == item->type()) ? static_cast<T>(item) : 0;
}
```

You should follow the example in the document http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsitem.html#type

Declare your `Type` and return it as result in `int type() const`